# SendKeys doesn't work correctly VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to press enter key by VB.NET...I tried lots of codes but no one worked.
I tried:

```
SendKeys.Send("(Enter)")  

SendKeys.Send(Keys.Enter)

SendKeys.Send("Enter")
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using WPF or Winforms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but from this link in MSDN Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx

...you should be using:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

or

```
SendKeys.Send("~")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Andy states, Visual Basic has some default Constants built in. Try using `vbCrLf` or `vbCR` all of them will work.

i.e.

```
SendKeys.Send(vbCrLf)
```

or

```
SendKeys.Send(vbCr)
```